# How to count monthly retention user in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, retention, churn

I have raw data as below. With each line is the record of an transaction of user, and the month when they made the transaction 
[image]

What I want is to calculate the number of user who made order in a month and the number of repeated user (RETENTION) from last month, then I can know how many % of user is repeated user.

The desired result should look like this 
[image]

How can I do it in bigquery?

Comment: What is the data type of month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to do it is through a self-join with the same table and a 1-month delay. That way, we match user&month combinations with user&previous-month to see if it's a returning user. For example, using the 2M row public table `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories` and a particular user:

[image]

Note that `prev_month` is **null** (we used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) for **2014-02-01** as the user was **not** active during **2014-01-01**. We are joining on author and lagged months with:

```sql
FROM authors AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN authors AS b
ON a.author = b.author
AND a.month = DATE_ADD(b.month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Then we count a user as repeating if the previous month was not null:

```sql
COUNT(a.author) AS num_users,
COUNTIF(b.month IS NOT NULL) AS num_returning_users
```

Note that we do not use `DISTINCT` here as we already grouped by author and month combinations when defining `orders` as CTE. You might need to take this into account for other examples.

Full query:

```sql
WITH
  authors AS (
  SELECT
    author,
    DATE_TRUNC(DATE(time_ts), MONTH) AS month
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`
  WHERE
    author IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1,2)

SELECT
  *,
  ROUND(100*SAFE_DIVIDE(num_returning_users,
      num_users),2) AS retention
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.month,
    COUNT(a.author) AS num_users,
    COUNTIF(b.month IS NOT NULL) AS num_returning_users
  FROM
    authors AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    authors AS b
  ON
    a.author = b.author
    AND a.month = DATE_ADD(b.month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1
  LIMIT 100)
```

and results snippet:

[image]

which are correct results, i.e. for `2007-03-01`:

[image]

Performance is not too fancy but in this case we are selecting only the fields needed for the aggregated data so scanned data is low and execution time not too high (~5s).

An alternative is to use `EXISTS()` inside `COUNTIF()` instead of the join 
but it takes longer for me (~7s). [Query](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/d49e704134b985910c40d4e9c5fb3ab4)

Comment: Super, it's exactly what I need. Thank you very much, cannot recognize that the LEFT JOIN and date_add can be used to solve my problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking at the previous month, then do the following:

- Convert the months to numbers.
- Aggregate the data at the user/month level.

Then you can just use `lag()`:

```
select month,
       count(*) as num_users,
       countif(prev_month_int = month_int - 1) as prev_num_users,
       countif(prev_month_int = month_int - 1) / count(*) as repeat_rate
from (select mu.*,
             lag(month_int) over (partition by userid order by month_int) as prev_month_int
      from (select month, userid, count(*) as num_orders,
                   cast(split(month, '-')[ordinal(1)] as int64) * 12 + cast(split(month, '-')[ordinal(2)] as int64) as month_int
            from t
            group by month, userid
           ) mu
     ) mu
group by month;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, though I have some problem using this method when the year change, ie Jan 2020 vs Dec 2019, just months in number form cause error.

Comment: @AnhHoang . . . The `month_int` column is designed to handle that situation.  Isn't it consecutive with no gaps, regardless of year?